# Unable to render outlook invitation on different email service providers

Tags: java, outlook, jakarta-mail

I am sending an outlook invitation using java mail to four different email servers:

```
web.de
gmx.net
gmail.com
company's private email server (which is configured on outlook)
```

The invitation is rendered/previewed on gmail only but we need to render/preview it on every platform.

My main class is

```
public class Email {

// Constants for the ICalendar methods.
public static final String METHOD_CANCEL = "CANCEL";
public static final String METHOD_PUBLISH = "PUBLISH";
public static final String METHOD_REQUEST = "REQUEST";
// Apply this organizer, if no organizer is given.
private static final String DEFAULT_ORGANIZER = "zain@company.com";
// Common ICalendar fields.
private String method;
private Calendar beginDate;
private Calendar endDate;
private String location;
private int uid;
private String description;
private String subject;
private String organizer;

/*
* @param args
*/
public static void main(String[] args) {
try {
Email email = new Email();
email.send();
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
System.exit(0);
}
}

public void send() throws Exception {
try {
String from = "mansoor@company.com";
Properties prop = new Properties();

Address[] receivers = new InternetAddress[] {
new InternetAddress("abc@company.com")
, new InternetAddress("abc@gmail.com")
, new InternetAddress("abc@web.de")
, new InternetAddress("abc@gmx.de")
};

prop.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
prop.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.company.com");
prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator() {
protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
return new PasswordAuthentication("smtp@company.com", "password");
}
};

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, authenticator);
// Define message
MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
message.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
message.addRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, receivers);
message.setSubject("Outlook Meeting Request Using JavaMail");

this.subject = "Meeting Request Test Subject";
this.description = "PLEASE IGNORE THIS MAIL AS IT IS A TEST.";
this.beginDate = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 07-01, 17, 19, 00);
this.endDate = new GregorianCalendar(2018, 07-01, 17, 19, 45);
this.method = Email.METHOD_REQUEST;
this.location = "Office # 13";

// Create the calendar part
BodyPart calendarPart = new MimeBodyPart();
// Fill the message
calendarPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-  classes:calendarmessage");
calendarPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
calendarPart.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Test_invite1.ics");
calendarPart.setFileName("Test_invite1");
calendarPart.setDataHandler(
new DataHandler(
new ByteArrayDataSource(createMessage(), "text/calendar")));// very important

// Create a Multipart
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
// Add part one
multipart.addBodyPart(calendarPart);

// Put parts in message
message.setContent(multipart);

// send message
Transport.send(message);

for(Address receiver: receivers){
System.out.println(receiver);
}

} catch (MessagingException me) {
System.out.println("Failed sending email");
me.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception ex) {
System.out.println("Failed sending email");
ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
System.out.println("End sending email");
System.exit(0);
}
}

public String createMessage() {
// Create the proper date format string required by the ICalendar spec.
final SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmmss");
final String stringBeginDate = formatter.format(beginDate.getTime());
final String stringEndDate = formatter.format(endDate.getTime());
// Encode the description => mark new lines.
final String encodedDescription = description.replaceAll("\r\n", "\\\\n");
// Use the default organizer if none is given.
if (this.organizer == null) {
this.organizer = DEFAULT_ORGANIZER;
}
// Content string as array.
String[] contents = {
"BEGIN:VCALENDAR",
"METHOD:" + this.method,
"BEGIN:VEVENT",
"UID:" + this.uid,
"DTSTART:" + stringBeginDate,
"DTEND:" + stringEndDate,
"LOCATION:" + this.location,
"DESCRIPTION:" + encodedDescription,
"ATTENDEE;RSVP=TRUE:MAILTO:" + this.organizer,
"ORGANIZER:" + this.organizer,
"SUMMARY:" + this.subject,
"END:VEVENT",
"END:VCALENDAR"
};
// Build a well-formatted string from the array.
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String line : contents) {
if (sb.length() > 0) {
sb.append("\n");
}
sb.append(line);
}
return sb.toString();
}
}
```

Please add comment if you have any ambiguity before down voting. I have seen so many question on stackoverflow.com but found no proper solution.

Comment: Different mail readers will display messages differently. If you're talking about the web based mail readers associated with the other mail servers, they may not display the invitation as you would like because they have no integration with a calendar service.

Comment: @BillShannon When an invitation is sent directly from outlook then it is rendered/displayed on all the mail readers (either web based or desktop).

Comment: Look at the raw MIME content of the message sent from Outlook and compare it with the raw MIME content of the message you're sending with JavaMail.  You should be able to use JavaMail to create a message with the same MIME structure as the message sent from Outlook, which should allow the mail reader to display it the same way.

Comment: @BillShannon I have checked it, it's same. No big difference is found except than the charset which I think, is not an issue.

Comment: Only those invitations are available which are sent as an attachment :(

Comment: If you're sending a message that's indistinguishable from a message sent from Outlook, then I don't know why the mail reader would be displaying it differently.

Comment: I have got another scenario last night! I was sending the invitation as an attachment but it didn't showed up on web mail reader, I configured it on outlook and found out that there was an attachment with my last test mail. This is very strange for me!